# The meaning of 「どこでも傘下」

Tags: meaning, words

The sentence goes as follows:

> 「**ドコデモ傘下**なので受けるのは当然携帯電話絡みの問い合わせだ。」

The sentence is uttered after the reader is told about a woman who works in a call center. She is checking the daily "briefing-mails" and then it is uttered.

The preceding sentence:

> 早くもどこかのブースで着信の合図がある

It is later revealed that there have been problems with telephones services all over town.

I really do not know what to make of the part in bold. My best shot at it would be that it expresses the fact that the company (the call center belongs to) is affiliated with all sorts of things (and therefore with the telephone problems as well). However, the meaning of 「傘下」is a mystery to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems the company called ドコデモ is a telecommunications company especially mobile network service. The company she works at should be a subsidiary company of ドコデモ. I am not sure what she is actually doing though, she might be responding the customers' request due to erratic connection all over the town.

Anyway 傘下{さんか} literally means "under the umbrella". If you open the umbrella up, the shape is like a pyramid, right? So, it seems like describing a "hierarchy". The company she works at might always need to work according to the order from the parent company 「ドコデモ」.

Comment: Might be obvious, but ドコデモ is a reference to a major mobile carrier in Japan [ドコモ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTT_Docomo).

Comment: I know the minor changes should be authors' concern for copyright. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Thank you! I feel like a gigantic idiot for not realizing that it is simply a name.

Comment: It's worth noting that “under the umbrella of...” is used in more or less the same way in English
https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/come-work-etc-under-the-umbrella-of-something

Comment: @Himula I don't think it's your fault. ドコデモ (as well as the original ドコモ) has taken over a plain word as their brand, so it's hard to guess if you don't know such a thing exists. Much as same as you wouldn't understand how people could "tweet", or write a report without "Word".

Comment: @broccoli facemask. Thank you for saying that it really encourages me to simply keep going with studying Japanese! The "Word" example is absolutely perfect. In the end I guess these are all things we have to go through when learning a foreign language.